# Set angle to zero in function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, camanjs

This function is from CamanJS library. This is the code for tiltshift effect of plugin

```
Caman.Filter.register("tiltShift", function(opts) {
  var defaults, gradient;

  defaults = {
    center: {
      x: this.dimensions.width / 2,
      y: this.dimensions.height / 2
    },
    angle: 45,
    focusWidth: 200,
    startRadius: 3,
    radiusFactor: 1.5,
    steps: 3
  };
  opts = Util.extend(defaults, opts);
  opts.angle *= Math.PI / 180;
  gradient = getLinearGradientMap(this.dimensions.width, this.dimensions.height, opts.center.x, opts.center.y, opts.angle, opts.focusWidth, true);
  return this.processPlugin("compoundBlur", [gradient, opts.startRadius, opts.radiusFactor, opts.steps]);
});
```

I supplied the following values as parameters.

```
this.tiltShift(600,400,300,200,0,200,true).render();
```

But the default angle is still 45. How do I change it?

Comment: I don't know what is `Util.extend` but maybe you should swap the `defaults` and `opts`? I mean `Util.extend(opts, defaults)`.

Comment: The function is from a library I can just pass the parameters.

Comment: Try to swap the arguments

Comment: Which two should I swap?

Comment: Change `opts = Util.extend(defaults, opts)` to `opts = Util.extend(opts, defaults)`

Comment: I can't modify the function. It is from a library.

Comment: Ok, in this case, maybe, you should pass the object instead of list of arguments, like `this.tiltShift({ angle: 28, ... })`?

Comment: No everything stop working Nothing is drawn on canvas. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Ok. Can you provide some documentation about `tiltShift`? I can't find it here: http://camanjs.com/api/

Comment: @AnatoliyArkhipov It's not documented, I've been looking. The only thing I can find is the source http://camanjs.com/docs/compoundBlur.html and the projects `Util.expend` http://camanjs.com/docs/util.html#section-4 , it's a pretty typical object extension function

Comment: Can you show errors from console for this call: `this.tiltShift({ angle: 28 })`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over [the documentation](http://camanjs.com/docs/util.html#section-4), the specific way to call this is:

```
tiltShift({ angle: 0 });
```

The call to `Util.extend()` in the method creates an object that has the properties of `defaults`, but is changed to any values that are supplied in `opts` (the object passed to `tiltShift()`).